# How to make a trigger that run when there is changes on specific column of different Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to ask about how to make a trigger that run when there are changes on different spreadsheet (**Source spreadsheet**) and on specific column.

I have **2 different spreadsheet** (**Source Spreadsheet and Target spreadsheet**) and the trigger will working on target spreadsheet when there are changes that happened in the specific column of the source spreadsheet. I've just made the code, but it's not working. **This code was made on the target spreadsheet**. I've already use the onEdit() and onChange() trigger, but nothing happen or run this script.

This code still show some error like:

> TypeError: e.source.openById is not a function

Here is the code that I've been made on the target spreadsheet:

```
function inChange(e) {
 var source_spreadsheet_sheetName = e.source.openById('').getName(); //ID of source spreadsheet
 var Row = e.source.getActiveCell().getRow();
 var Column = e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
 if (source_spreadsheet_sheetName == '' && Row >= 2 && Column == 2) { //the name of sheet from source spreadsheet and the specific column that has changes on it.
  myFunction(); //It will run the process of this myFunction script that I've been made on target spreadsheet
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the trigger set up correctly? Which sheet is the trigger set up for?

Comment: the trigger was set up for the target spreadsheet and its already correctly set up, because I run a different kind of trigger before this case and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: What type of trigger are you using?

Comment: I use the onChange @Cooper

Comment: I don't know my question is duplicating. Because with the suggested similar question, it has a difference purpose. Can you explain where the duplicates part or the detail?

Comment: If the trigger is set for the target spreadsheet, it would respond to changes made in the target spreadsheet, not the source spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain how you set up the trigger in the first place.

Comment: @TheMaster I apologize for my misunderstanding. So, if the trigger set on the target spreadsheet, then it will responding to changes in the target spreadsheet only and not the source spreadsheet

Comment: and if I want to detect changes that happen on the source spreadsheet, then I have to set up the trigger on the source spreadsheet and the code that will run have to change to transferring data to the target spreadsheet, right? @TheMaster

Comment: If you're setting the trigger manually, yes. However you can programmatically set up onChange for a different spreadsheet.

Comment: I think I set the trigger manually by using add trigger in the apps script. Would you explain how the programmatically for a different spreadsheet set up?

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger runs. But it fails on first line of code because you're calling a method that you cannot.

Several problems.

**Problem #1**

```
var source_spreadsheet_sheetName = e.source.openById('').getName();
```

the `openById` probably does not work because `source` is already of type `Spreadsheet` so you can directly call `getName` on it.

It should be

```
var source_spreadsheet_sheetName = e.source.getName();
```

**Problem #2**

There is no `getActiveCell` on a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), only on a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell).

```
// if you know the sheet name in advance
let sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME)
// or if you don't, get the active sheet (and don't use the line before)
let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()

let row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
let column = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
```

**Problem #3**

```
if (source_spreadsheet_sheetName == ''
```

A sheet name cannot be empty so this will never be true

Answer (score 0):

`source_spreadsheet == ''` cannot be true because it's the name of a spreadsheet

Comment: Sorry for the bad variables name, it's for the sheet name I thought. Because the first line, I try to get the sheet name of source spreadsheet.